# How to handle file upload name

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to handle file uploads and now I face a dilemma. I have two options that I actually think about using when handling file name:

Option 1:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s', sha1_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name']),$ext
```

Option 2:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], sprintf('./uploads/%s.%s', "name_$date", $ext
```

First will generate hash with sha1_file which doesn't look pretty (and I would like to get that uploaded file name from DB and show it on page) but prevents multiple same file uploads.

Second gets a nice looking file name but doesn't prevent duplicates (`file_exists` seems to recognize duplicate but I couldn't stop `move_upload_file`)

What would you suggest me to do to get nice file name without file upload duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a simple solution: You can create a temporary directory with the name of the sha1 hash and put in the filenames with their original name.

This way, multi file uploads will go to different directories if they are different, but you will keep the original file name.

Example:

```
$uploadDir = "/your upload dir";
$contentHash = sha1_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name']);
$tmpDir = $uploadDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $contentHash;
mkdir($tmpDir, 0777); 
// add filename validation before storing it! 
$fileName = $tmpDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES['pdf']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $fileName);
```

You will wind up with a directory structure like this:

- 01BADCOFFEE123

  - test.pdf
- (some other hash)

  - test.pdf
- ...

to later iterate the files, just use a recursive directory iterator:

```
$uploadDir = "/your upload dir";
$fileIterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($uploadDir), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);
```

No need to store anything in the database.

Comment: I thought about moving the sha1 file and that way renaming it but I don't know if I can get the same hash that way to move the file?

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. You need to: 1. get the hash from the file 2. create a temp directory with the name of the hash 3. move the uploaded file to this directory with its original name.  Whats wrong with that solution?

Comment: The problem is I can't get the hash to variable. If you know how to get just the hash please let me know.

Comment: I added a code example to be more clear. Are you saying that you always get the same hash? In this case chances are, that the file has not been transferred yet, although documentation indicates otherwise. In this case you need to move the file to another tmp file. Then get the hash. Then move to final location.

Comment: When I get some time I will check that out. What I'm saying is the file upload goes like: send form -> tmp dir with tmp name -> hash tmp file -> move to uploads dir. So sha1 and any hash happens when uploading file so I can't get the hash since file is already uploaded.

Comment: Ok it is definitely helpful (<15 rep so I "shadow upvoted" for now) but I dont really understand the "iterate" part so could you please explain it? The code for iteration is giving me "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(E: mpp\htdocs\php\bazy_danych\obiektowe\my\uploads" (thats just part of error). Also if I upload same file with different name it puts it in same folder which is nice but it is still uploading of the same file is there a way around this?

Comment: Could this be your problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153826/recursivedirectoryiterator-throws-unexpectedvalueexception-on-too-many-open-fil#7153854

You need to post the complete error message, and maybe the code part where you use the iterator.

Comment: Thing is I don't know what the iterate and recursive part is for - and for you to explain it... I don't think the comment section is fit for that. I handled my problem with your idea of creating folders with hash and then I added "ifs" to copy and delete file to where I want.

Answer (score 0):

Add your db record id to your file name that will looks good and mean it.

Comment: for now I'm not adding uploaded file to db untill I figure out how to handle this situation. But that is quite a puzzle for me.